# Possible outcomes of sums

Tags: summation, fractions, geometric-construction, binary-operations

Let $\mathrm{S}$ be a set of distinct 20 integers. A set $\mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{A}}$ is defined as $\mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{A}}:=\left\{\mathrm{s}_1+\mathrm{s}_2+\mathrm{s}_3 \mid \mathrm{s}_1, \mathrm{~s}_2, \mathrm{~s}_3 \in \mathrm{S}\right\}$. What is the smallest possible cardinality of $\mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{A}}$?

My progress so far: We're looking for the smallest possible cardinality of $T_A$, which is the set of sums of three distinct numbers from $S$, and $S$ is a set of 20 distinct integers.

To minimize the cardinality of $T_A$, we would aim to have as many sums repeating as possible. In other words, we want the sums to overlap as much as possible.

Consider the set of 20 integers to be $S = {1, 2, 3, ..., 20}$ for simplicity.

If we choose the smallest three numbers, the sum would be $1 + 2 + 3 = 6$. If we choose the largest three numbers, the sum would be $18 + 19 + 20 = 57$. Thus, the range of possible sums lies between 6 and 57.

However, not all values within this range can be achieved due to the restriction of using distinct integers for each sum. For instance, the value 7 cannot be achieved because there's no way to add three distinct positive integers from $S$ to get 7. Similarly, there will be several values within the range that cannot be achieved due to this restriction.

The problem is equivalent to finding the number of distinct elements in a multiset where we sum triplets from the multiset ${1, 2, ..., 20}$.

Comment: $1+2+4=7$. No way to achieve $7$?

Comment: See Lev V.F., Structure Theorem for Multiple Addition and Frobenius Problem, J. Number Th., 58, 1996, 79-88; addendum: 65, 1997, 96-100. Available at https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82292093.pdf

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for the reference. I went through the glimpse of the paper but still felt it is a bit more complicated compared to the original question. Maybe a bit simpler solution and more intuitive solution would exist for this particular question?!

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Did you try any of the references cited in Lev's paper? and, are you still claiming there's no way to achieve $7$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, I looked through Lev's references but could not find more concrete information. No, there is a way to achieve 7 - my bad!

Comment: Then maybe you want to edit your post to remove the assertion about $7$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest possible cardinality is $52$, which is achieved by $S=\{\,1,2,\dotsc,20\,\}$ (or by any $20$-term arithmetic progression.

Let the elements of $S$ be $a_1<a_2<\dotsb<a_{20}$. Then all the sums $a_1+a_2+a_r$, $3\le r\le20$, are distinct – that's $18$ sums.

All the sums $a_1+a_s+a_{20}$, $3\le s\le19$, are distinct from each other and from the first $18$ sums. That's another $17$ sums.

All the sums $a_t+a_{19}+a_{20}$, $2\le t\le18$, are distinct from each other, and from the previous sums. That's another $17$ sums.

Total: $18+17+17=52$.

The argument works for a set of $k$ distinct numbers, and gives a minimum of $3k-8$ sums.

Comment: This solution is wrong. For the $n=20$ case, it should be $58$. In general, for a set of $k$ distinct numbers, the arguments give a minimum of $3k - 2$ sums.

Comment: @Snow, for $k=3$, your formula says there should be seven sums. But for $k=3$, there there is only one sum of three numbers, $a_1+a_2+a_3$, and that agrees with $3k-8$.

Comment: @Snow, please be more careful when spelling users' names. The problem calls for the sum of *distinct* elements. You can't do $a_1+a_1+a_1$, as you do in the answer you posted.

Comment: I apologize for misspelling, I was commenting very fast and made a typo mistake. You are right, but nowhere actually was mentioned about the sum of distinct element in the problem statement, isn't it?

Comment: It is weird since the problem statement did not indicate any particular point about whether we can pick distinct elements from $S or they can be the same.

Comment: @Snow, in the 2nd paragraph of the question, it says, "the set of sums of three distinct numbers from $S$ ...."

Answer (score 0):

I'll find it for an arbitrary set $S$ with $n$ distinct integer.

Let $S=\left\{s_1, s_2, s_3, \cdots, s_n\right\}$ with $s_i<s_{i+1}$ for $i=1,2, \cdots, n-1$. $T_A$ contains at least $n$ distinct integers $3 s_1<3 s_2<\cdots<3 s_n$ since $3 s_i=s_i+s_i+s_i$ for all $i=1,2, \cdots, n$. Furthermore, $T_A$ contains at least $2(n-1)$ elements more since for every $i=1,2, \cdots, n-1$, there are two distinct elements $s_i+s_i+s_{i+1}$ and $s_i+s_{i+1}+s_{i+1}$ in $T_A$ between $3 s_i$ and $3 s_{i+1}$. Thus $T_A$ contains at least $3 n-2$ elements.

Let $S=\{0,1, \cdots, n-1\}$. Then clearly $T_A=\{0,1, \cdots, 3 n-3\}$ and $\left|T_A\right|=$ $3 n-2$. Thus minimal cardinality of $T_A$ is $3 n-2$. For the $n=20$ case, it is 58.

This is the solution I came up with, but I don't know whether I did something wrong or the above solution has some fallacy in solving. Can anyone verify these particular cases?